# Unsubscribing a subscriber using SSJS from a publication list based on cloudpages URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, unsubscribe

This is what I have so far from the help documentation and it doesn't seem to work

```
%%[ VAR @subKey SET @subKey = [Email Address] ]%%

<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core","1");
var subsKey = Variable.GetValue("@subKey");
var myList = List.Init("5778");
var status = myList.Subscribers.Unsubscribe(subsKey);

</script>
```

What am I not getting here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend logging an unsub event instead of toggling the status.  Logging unsub events ensures that all of the tracking data relating to the subscriber is recorded properly.  The system personalization strings in the send context will ensure your page has all of the necessary info.  This method also supports the unsubscribe granularity if your send is associated with a List or Publication List.

AMPscript is faster in this case.

To ensure that you're passing the subscriber context to the page, I'd recommend utilizing the [**CloudPagesURL**](https://ampscript.guide/cloudpagesurl) function in your unsub link (where `123` is the Page ID of your CloudPage).

```html
<a href="%%=CloudPagesURL(123)=%%">one-click unsubscribe</a>
```

Page ID `123` should contain something like this:

```html
%%[

var @debug
var @jid
var @listid
var @batchid
var @email
var @skey
var @reason
var @unsubscribeAll

set @debug = 0
set @jid = AttributeValue("jobid")
set @listid = AttributeValue("listid")
set @batchid = AttributeValue("_JobSubscriberBatchID")
set @email = AttributeValue("emailaddr")
set @skey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
set @reason = "One-Click Unsubscribe"
set @unsubscribeAll = RequestParameter("ua")

/* if we know the subscriber */
if not empty(@skey) then

   var @lue
   var @lue_prop
   var @lue_statusCode
   var @overallStatus
   var @requestId
   var @Response
   var @Status
   var @Error

   /* if unsubscribing from all, then set the job, batch and listids to blank, effectively doing a global unsub */
   if @unsubscribeAll == "1" then
     set @jid = ""
     set @listid = ""
     set @batchid = ""
   endif

   /* create a request to inject an unsub event into the LogUnsubEvent platform table */
   set @lue = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent")

   /*
    In order to invoke the request, we need to associate the following information with it to define the subscriber context and the job context:

    1. Subscriber Key
    2. JobId associated with the email send
    3. ListID the email was sent to
    4. BatchID the email was sent to
    5. Reason for the unsub
   */

   /* 1. define and associate Subscriber Key to the request */
   set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @skey)
   AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

   /* 2. define and associate JobID to the request */
   if not empty(@jid) then
    set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "JobID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @jid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
   endif

   /* 3. define and associate ListID to the request */
   if not empty(@listid) then
     set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
     SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "ListID")
     SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @listid)
     AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
   endif

   /* 4. define and associate BatchID to the request */
   if not empty(@batchid) then
    set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "BatchID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @batchid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
   endif

   /* 5. define and associate unsub reason to the request */
   set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "Reason")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @reason)
   AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

   /* finally, you invoke the request */
   set @lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@lue, @overallStatus, @requestId)

   /* extract messages from the response */
   set @Response = Row(@lue_statusCode, 1)
   set @Status = Field(@Response,"StatusMessage")
   set @Error = Field(@Response,"ErrorCode")

endif

if @debug == 1 then
  output(concat("<br>jid: ", @jid))
  output(concat("<br>listid: ", @listid))
  output(concat("<br>batchid: ", @batchid))
  output(concat("<br>email: ", @email))
  output(concat("<br>skey: ", @skey))
  output(concat("<br>reason: ", @reason))
  output(concat("<br>unsubscribeAll: ", @unsubscribeAll))
  output(concat("<br>overallStatus: ", @overallStatus))
  output(concat("<br>requestId: ", @requestId))
  output(concat("<br>Response: ", @Response))
  output(concat("<br>Status: ", @Status))
  output(concat("<br>Error: ", @Error))
endif

]%%
```